# How to properly do a POST request from react-native to express.js & mySQL backend

Tags: javascript, mysql, react-native, express, fetch-api

I created an express.js backend with mySql database as suggested by these series of tutorial [first part here](https://medium.com/@kiddy.xyz/tutorial-restful-api-node-js-express-mysql-part-1-527868bfb9d1) and [second part here](https://medium.com/@kiddy.xyz/tutorial-restful-api-node-js-express-mysql-part-2-eff96ebb4b7f). Tested all the routes using Postman and already works fine.

Then, using react-native, i tried a simple Get request to fetch data from a table in the database :

```
<Button title='Test MySQL Connection' 
   onPress = {()=>{
     fetch('http://my_laptop_IP:3000/users')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(users => alert(users))}}
 />
```

This easily works fine.

However, when i tried to insert a row in the table using Post, it failed :

```
<Button title='Test MySQL Connection' 
   onPress={()=>{    
     fetch('http://my_laptop_IP:3000/users', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {       
         Accept: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
         first_name:'Cell',
         last_name: 'First_form',
       })
     })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((response) => {
        alert(response);
      })
     .catch((error) => alert('Error ' + error));
    }}
 />
```

Error screenshot for the express backend as follows : 
[image]

And this is displayed in my virtual device emulator :

[image]

have tried to change the header part of the fetch request like this :

```
headers: {
   Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
```

still no luck..

Comment: Looks like the server is not able to parse the body params. Can you post the server code where you reading the first_name and last_name

Comment: @nithin i have 5 server files : server.js, routes.js, controller.js, res.js, conn.js. This is the snippet from controller.js : ```exports.createUsers = function(req, res) {
    
    var first_name = req.body.first_name;
    var last_name = req.body.last_name;

    connection.query('INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name) values (?,?)',
    [ first_name, last_name ], 
    function (error, rows, fields){
        if(error){
            console.log(error)
        } else{
            response.ok("Berhasil menambahkan user!", res)
        }
    });
};```

Comment: @nithin the complete source can be found at the tutorial links in my original question (sorry it's in Indonesian)

Comment: I believe, For access to req.body you need to add body-parser middleware to express

Comment: @nithin could you please post the syntax? Or maybe an answer with sample, please?

Comment: @nithin anyway, i think the backend is fine. As i said, i have tested using Postman app, with successful results

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing JSON as request body you can use

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        first_name: "Cell",
        last_name: "First_form"
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => alert("Error " + error))
```

Also you might need to add cors module to your server.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');


  app = express(),
  
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  controller = require("./controller");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require("./routes");
routes(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log("Learn Node JS With Kiddy, RESTful API server started on: " + port);
```